# Target .Net 4.0 when using Windows 8 / VS2012

Tags: c#, .net, ilmerge

I am having some issues building a merged DLL to target .net4.0 on a windows 8 machine. I can successfully build individual .net4.0 dlls in VS2012 so I do not have this problem:

[Targeting .NET 4.0 in VS 2012 on Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482746/targeting-net-4-0-in-vs-2012-on-windows-8)

I have come across the following excellent blog post which discuss my issue:

http://www.mattwrock.com/post/2012/02/29/What-you-should-know-about-running-ILMerge-on-Net-45-Beta-assemblies-targeting-Net-40.aspx

and also:

[Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748055/could-not-load-type-system-runtime-compilerservices-extensionattribute-from-as)

which suggests I use the following syntax during the merge:

```
/targetplatform:"v4,C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0"
```

Unfortunately in windows 8 I do not have this directory. I can think of the following possible solutions but would be interested to know if anyone has already solved this.

1. Copy the .net 4.0 assemblies from a windows 7 machine into the above directory manually.
2. Find the .net 4.0 assemblies being used by VS2012 and reference those.
3. ??

Comment: That's surely because you simply never had .NET 4.0 installed on that machine.  A Windows 8 machine with VS2012 only has .NET 4.5.  You should therefore only build projects that target 4.5.  Which automatically solves this problem as well.

Comment: @HansPassant - You make a good point but I still need create assemblies for .net2.0+ systems. This is not a problem for .net2.0 and .net3.5 as those are made available in Windows 8, the problem was with .net4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks for the comments and feedback. A working (hacky) solution was to do the following:

1. Create a new directory on windows 8, `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v4.0`.
2. Go to a windows 7 machine, which does not have .net4.5 installed, and copy the contents of the folder `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`
3. Paste the files from step 2 into the folder created in step 1.

I was then able to correctly reference the .net4.0 assemblies in Windows 8 using the following:

```
/targetplatform:"v4,C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v4.0"
```

Tested as working ok.

Comment: Your other option is to install VS2k10 along side it.

Comment: @sixlettervariables - I had VS2010 installed from the beginning, that didn't help.

Comment: It added it for me, you must have a bizarre config. Are you using the Express versions?

Comment: @sixlettervariables - Yea, something does seem strange for my setup, no idea what. I have ultimate for both.

Answer (score 1):

I am also using Windows 8, and VS 2012 but have not come across that issue (and surely, a bunch of other people are fine as well). Very simply, it may just be that you have v3.5 or v4.5 installed and that means you need to install v4.0 framework (... again if you already tried).

I also found that the folder path you gave did not take me anywhere on my PC, but this path did;

```
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\
```

Can you try that path on your PC and see if there is a v4.0 folder there.

Comment: I do have the directory "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\" but I only have v3.0, v3.5 in there.

Comment: Can you try @ `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\VSTO40\v4.0.Framework`?

Comment: @Ronak - That directory does exist but only contains Microsoft.Office... and Microsoft.VisualStudio... assemblies.

Comment: Sounds pretty random, I think I read in one of your links that installing VS2010 solved the problem for someone, maybe just install the Express version to see if that puts the right DLLs in the right places?

Comment: @KaushalDeSilva - Apologies, I should have mentioned that I have both VS2010 and VS2012 already installed. I may have a go at reinstalling.

Comment: @KaushalDeSilva - Many thanks for the feedback but I managed to get it working by using solution 1 above, answer posted.