# Visual Studio 2012 4.0 Targeting Pack not installing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.0

I'm trying to install the VS2012 4.0.3 targeting pack for VS. However, when I run it, it gives me this error:

> Installation Requirements:
>
> Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack was not found. Please
>   repair your installation for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 in order to
>   get this update.

However, I'm trying to install it to VS2012... I've uninstalled VS2010 (using the KB uninstaller, I think I did the full uninstallation), and wiped its folder in Program Files (x86) as well (I don't need it, and I prefer 2012). What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: VS2012 supports targetting 4.0 out of the box there isn't a need to install anything.  Furthermore `.NET Framework 4.0` and `.NET Framework 4.5` cannot both exist on the system considering `.NET Framework 4.5` is replacement for `.NET Framework 4.0`

Comment: @Ramhound Well, it doesn't for me. I'm trying to open a .NET 4 project, and it is prompting me to install the .NET 4 targeting pack. I don't appreciate the downvote because you don't think this should happen.

Comment: @Ramhound You could've just flagged this as a duplicate instead...

Comment: Further research indicates I might have been wrong about VS2012 supporting this out of the box. Although I still believe I am correct based on the documentation on the MTP itself. It appears this question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567193/multi-targeting-net-framework-4-and-visual-studio-2012 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482746/targeting-net-4-0-in-vs-2012-on-windows-8

Comment: I Remove prior comments and replaced it with a generic response linking to the two related questions.